# what is turning http to https?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

On my wordpress site, if I set the site url to a "https" one, then even though I type in a "http" link into my browser's address bar, it will turn into "https". I'd like to know that in a deeper layer(probably server side?), what is making this possible? I've thought of .htaccess, but there seems to be non related, as shown in the following：

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So what is it

Comment: There's nothing in that `.htaccess` to redirect http to https. You'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: The settings  you're looking for will be in your httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably check on your Wordpress settings under 'Settings > General'.

What's currently set for your Wordpress Address and Site Address.

The Site Addres setting is the address people will use to reach your WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like siteurl has been set with the HTTPS link. Che for the links on the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` fields on the General settings page of wp-admin. Both should have links beginning with http.